# i tried to install moq package but there are some error during moq installing

Tags: moq

PM> Install-Package Moq -Version 4.8.2 
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Moq.4.8.2' with respect to project 'CG.MMS.Test', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'

Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'NUnit.3.10.1' from source 'D:\devops\MMS_SVN_7_MAY_2018\packages'.At line:1 char:1

- Install-Package Moq -Version 4.8.2
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Can any one please help me for resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Visual Studio Package Manager to the latest version, to do it follow below steps

In Visual Studio, "Tools" -> "Extensions and Updates" -> expand the "Updates" node -> select "Visual Studio Gallery"
check Package Manager update in the list of updates at the right side of the dialog and click the "Update" button beside it.